# Insert Plugin on a custom page

Tags: plugins, headers

May I know if I can insert curtain plugin on a page. For example, if I edit page `header.php`. How do I want to insert a plugin on that page. The plugin that I want to use is **Huge IT Image Gallery**.

I tried to edit `header.php` and insert the code such as `[huge_it_gallery id="4"]` provided by the plugin, but the image gallery did not appear. Do I need to insert a `<script></script>` or the plugin directory on my `header.php` page.

I am new and still studying on the wordpress development.

Comment: [do_shortcode()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) will trigger a shortcode. Otherwise it typically only happens in post content.

Comment: Thanks for the details @jgraup. Do you have an example on how to use it for my case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[do_shortcode](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/) Is a function which executes shortcodes in WordPress

In your case you should use it in your header.php file as the following:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[huge_it_gallery id="4"]'); ?>
```